# Select only the first option

Tags: jquery

How do I select only the first option instead of having to find the value?

This selects the option with a value of "" but how do i select option:first

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).addClass('select-placeholder');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('select-placeholder')
    }
});
$('select').change();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the selected option and check whether it is the first child

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').is(':first-child')) {
      $(this).addClass('select-placeholder');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('select-placeholder')
    }
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5LDBC/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("select option:first-child");
```

This will select the first option.